# Geometry Question - What is the length of the missing height?

Tags: geometry, triangles

Gary, $G$, can just see the top of a radio mast, $R$, over a wall $W$. Gary is $15\,\mathrm{m}$ from the wall. The wall is $45\,\mathrm{m}$ from the radio mast. The wall is $2.7\,\mathrm{m}$ high. Calculate the height of the radio mast, marked $h$ on the diagram.

[image]

---

How would you found the missing length $h$? I was thinking of doing Tan, Cos and Sin but I'm not that sure and I also had the idea of doing $15$ $+$ $45$ $=$ $60$ and then $2.7$ something. I know the answer is $10.79$ but I have no idea how that was worked out. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: What do you know about the ratio of the corresponding sides of similar triangles?

Comment: the small triangle is similar to the large one? Do I need to multiply $2.7$ by $3$ as $15$ times by $3$ is $45$ but then what?

Comment: @HonkyHanka : Is the side of the larger triangle 45 or 60?

Comment: no but it's not correct. the answer is apparently $10.79$ but I don't know how that was worked out.

Comment: Edit the question and explain what you have done, and someone here will be able to tell you what is wrong.

Comment: Is the $2.7$ an approximation?  If it were $2.6975$, the stated answer of $10.19$ would be correct.

Comment: no. it's $2.7$, no an approximation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The smallest triangle is similar to the larger triangle, so we can use ratios to solve for the height $h$ of the larger triangle. $$\dfrac {\text{(height)}_\text{large}}{\text{(base)}_{\text{large}}} = \dfrac {\text{(height)}_{\text{small}}}{\text{(base)}_{\text{small}}}$$

$$\dfrac{h}{15+45} = \dfrac{2.7}{15}$$

Comment: ok, I know what you mean but how do you get $10.79$ from that. I did $15$ devided by $2.7$ but that's totally wrong

Comment: *Cross multiply*: $$15h = 2.7(15+45) = 2.7\times 60$$ Solve for $h$: $$h = \dfrac{2.7 \times 60}{15} = 2.7 \times 4 = 10.8$$

Comment: $162$ devided by $15$ $=$ $10.8$ yaaay! thxs

Comment: just wondering, do you know the Tan Method on a calculator?

Comment: Yes, you can find the smallest angle (left-most angle in your image), let's call it $\theta$: $\tan \theta = \dfrac {2.7}{15}$ (opposite/adjacent). Then we also know that $\tan\theta = \dfrac{h}{60}$. This means that $\dfrac{2.7}{15} = \dfrac{h}{60}$, which is what we found to be true above.

Comment: @amWhy: Always helpful! +1

Comment: Thanks, it's a calculator paper so I needed the calculator method, thanks again though. :)